Python Streamlit, need to click twice on the element to submit change on st.data_editor
I need to click twice to update the dataframe and show updated data correctly. The first click is working fine but then i need to always click the second time
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

def initialize_df():
    if 'df' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': [True, True ,True],'Column 2': [4, 5, 6]
 })
if 'df' not in st.session_state:
    
    initialize_df()

# Callback function for when the data editor changes
def data_editor_changed():

    st.session_state.df.update(st.session_state.df)
    
st.session_state.df = st.data_editor(st.session_state.df, on_change=data_editor_changed, key='ed')


Please help, I have tried a lot of combinations.

maybe better create minimal reproducible example which we could simply copy and run.
